# Sending data and loading only a div with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I load a specific div of an external file in a specific div of the current file after sending data with jquery-ajax?

For instance, how can I put .first inside #solution1 and second inside #solution2

HTML:

```
<div id="button">button</div>
<div id="solution1">solution1</div>
<br><br>
<div id="solution2">solution2</div>
```

JQUERY/AJAX:

```
$(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.post("proces.php"
        , { id: 299 } 
        ,function (result) {
            $("#solution1").html(result); // this works
            //$("#solution1").html(result .first); // this does not work
            //$("#solution2").html(result .second); 
        }// end function result
        );//end post
    });//end click
})
```

PROCES:

```
<?php
include("../../externs/includes/connexio.php");

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bookmarks
                              WHERE id = '$id' ");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $minut = $row["minut"];     
?>

<div class="first"> <?php echo $minut; ?> </div>
<div class="second"> <?php echo $minut . ' something else'; ?> </div>

<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Better return json object and load `$("#solution1").html(result.first)`

Comment: @u_mulder: I have updated my code there was a mistake it should be .first and not #first, because is a class. But this was not the problem

Comment: It doesn't mater, `result.first` in my comment is accessing `first` property of `result` object.

Comment: I tried, it does not work. it loads nothing

Comment: So show your attempt.

Comment: @u_mulder: I just copy paste your line of code instead of $("#solution1").html(result);  Do I need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

In php

```
include("../../externs/includes/connexio.php");

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bookmarks
                              WHERE id = '$id' ");

$first=array();
$second=array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $minut = $row["minut"];     
$tmp='<div class="first">'.$minut'.</div>';
$tmp2='<div class="second">'.$minut . ' something else </div>';
array_push($first,$tmp);
array_push($second,$tmp2);

}
echo json_encode(array('first'=>$first,'second'=>$second));
```

And In html

```
$(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.post("proces.php"
        , { id: 299 } 
        ,function (result) {
            var res=$.parseJSON(result);
            $("#solution1").html(res.first); 
            $("#solution2").html(res .second); 
        }
        );
    });    })
```

Comment: i am using $.parseJSON(result); to parse json

Comment: But you ajax does not expecting result as a json. Either add `"json"` dataType to your success callback after `}, "json");` or use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get()/$.post()`.

Comment: and you don't need to parse json as that is a proper valid json. parsing only done on json string like `"{'key':'val'}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("#solution1").html($(result).find('.first').get(0));
$("#solution2").html($(result).find('.second').get(0));
```

```js
var str = '<div><span class="one">1</span><span class="two">2</span></div>';

$('button').click(function(){
   $('body').append($(str).find('.one').get(0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>alert</button>
```

even you can  use `.load()` like this too:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#solution1").load("proces.php .first", { id: 299 });
    $("#solution1").load("proces.php .second", { id: 299 });
});
```

Comment: The load is a good solution. Thank you. The first it does not work

Comment: @Nrc you mentioned it work in your question so i thought to suggest you something like this.

Comment: @Nrc you can try after removing `.outerHTML` from the first.